# Is there any advantage over sending multiple files compared to one file?

Tags: file, networking, ethernet, tcp

Is there any performance gain sending many files versus one file over TCP/IP?

*(Aside from being able to only resend failed files if the connection goes down)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 3-packet connect overhead and a 4-packet close overhead. The latter is asynchronous. The effect asymptotes to zero as file size increases.

Comment: Thanks EJP... really, anything but the smallest of files has an insignificant overhead then.